# Нужна помощь с выводом остатков по складам Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Аспро Оптимус. Есть компонент вывода остатков по складам bitrix:catalog.store.amount с помощью его выводятся остатки в Табах - код вот такой:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:catalog.store.amount", "main", array(
"PER_PAGE" => "10",
"USE_STORE_PHONE" => $arParams["USE_STORE_PHONE"],
"SCHEDULE" => $arParams["SCHEDULE"],
"USE_MIN_AMOUNT" => $arParams["USE_MIN_AMOUNT"],
"MIN_AMOUNT" => $arParams["MIN_AMOUNT"],
"ELEMENT_ID" => $arResult["ID"],
"STORE_PATH" => $arParams["STORE_PATH"],
"MAIN_TITLE" => $arParams["MAIN_TITLE"],
"MAX_AMOUNT"=>$arParams["MAX_AMOUNT"],
"USE_ONLY_MAX_AMOUNT" => $arParams["USE_ONLY_MAX_AMOUNT"],
"SHOW_EMPTY_STORE" => $arParams['SHOW_EMPTY_STORE'],
"SHOW_GENERAL_STORE_INFORMATION" => $arParams['SHOW_GENERAL_STORE_INFORMATION'],
"USE_ONLY_MAX_AMOUNT" => $arParams["USE_ONLY_MAX_AMOUNT"],
"USER_FIELDS" => $arParams['USER_FIELDS'],
"FIELDS" => $arParams['FIELDS'],
"STORES" => $arParams['STORES'],
),
$component
);?>
```

Копирую его в другое место чтобы вывести остатки по складам в нужное место, он выводит, для товаров все норм, для торговых предложений тоже, но только для торгового предложения которое сразу выставляется. Если поменять на другое (желтый / голубой) на скрине, в табе меняется количество, а там где надо - нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже на проблему с js селектором по котором обновляется контент после измененич параметров товара

Comment: я это уже понял, а не подскажете как решить эту проблему?